# Why axios.interceptors call many times? React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

This is what i came up with , but everytime i try to move around my screens in my app and do api calls its sends 3 console logs with the interceptors calls.

1. The 1st Api call only sends 1 request but after it sends 3/4 calls of interceptors
2. Im using Expo with react Native

```
let axiosInterceptor = null;
    
    axiosInterceptor = axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {

        if (!!axiosInterceptor || axiosInterceptor === 0 || axiosInterceptor >= 1) {
            axios.interceptors.request.eject(axiosInterceptor);
            
        }

        if (config.url == "login/login") { //quando faz login não necessita dos headrs de autorização (Bearer Token)
            return config;
        }
        setIsLoading(true);
        //global.isWaitingRequestAnswers = true;
        //console.log("request isWaitingRequestAnswers", global.isWaitingRequestAnswers);
        const configToken = SecureStore.getItemAsync('token').then(token => {
            console.log("Axios Call: " + config.url)
            // console.log("Axios Call Token: "+token)
            // console.log(token)
            config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
            return config;
        });
        return configToken;

    }
        , function (error) {
            console.log('Error => axios.interceptors.request');
            console.log(error);
        });
```

**Updated **

[Axios Call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A08Vg.png)

**Updated  1 **

```
 async function getInventario () {

var dados = null;
await axios.get('inventario/index')
.then((response) => {
    dados = response.data;
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
});
return dados;
```

}

[Network Reponse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ag0Qu.png)

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
    setIsLoading(false);
    //global.isWaitingRequestAnswers = false;
    //console.log("response isWaitingRequestAnswers", global.isWaitingRequestAnswers);
    return response;
}, error => {
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
        authContext.signOut(); //logout -> go to Login Page
    }
    console.log('Error => axios.interceptors.request');
    console.log(error);
});
```

i have this code in the end it could help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SecureStore.getItemAsync('token')` is asyncronous, you must wait response, change headers and then return `config` but your code do it syncronous. As a result headers is not updated yet but you returned config already. Example with `async/await`:

```
const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
let axiosInterceptor = false;
let requests = [];

const instance = axios.create();   
instance.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {

if (config.url === "login/login") {
    return config;
}

requests.push(config);

if(!axiosInterceptor) {
  axiosInterceptor = !axiosInterceptor;
  setIsLoading(true);

  const token = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('token');
  axiosInterceptor = !axiosInterceptor;
  requests.map(req => {
    req.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
    return instance(req)
  });
 }
 requests = [];
 return {
    ...config,
    cancelToken: new CancelToken((cancel) => cancel('Cancel repeated 
    request'))
 };
}, function (error) {
    console.log('Error => axios.interceptors.request');
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: I changed my code acording to your tip and i kept on getting 3 calls after 1st api request , i updated my post with a picture of what is showing , this is not a big deal , but it slows my api requests ,cause my 1st one is much faster than the rest

Comment: On each request `interceptors.request` send `SecureStore.getItemAsync('token');`  so you have 3 calls after 1st api request

Comment: If you have more then 1 parallel requests you must abort `SecureStore.getItemAsync('token');` after first call

Comment: would you mind elaborate how could you abort after 1st call, because during the whole application process i do multiple calls .

Comment: I edited answer. Add all request in array after call, then calling only first `SecureStore.getItemAsync('token');` , waiting response, after re-calling all aborted requests with new token.

Comment: For some reason after i made this changes the result comes undefined

Comment: Edited CancelToken

Comment: Still no luck it comes Null, im really sorry for wasting your time with this .

Comment: What behavior ? When comes Null ? more info please

Comment: You must undestand logic and then you will fix all errors myself

Comment: I updated my post with how i get the info from axios . my response there comes null

Comment: Why you see response ? You problem is (The 1st Api call only sends 1 request but after it sends 3/4 calls of interceptors)

Comment: How your requests work after changes?

Comment: Why response return null  is the next question

Comment: my requests come undefined , i see reponse because after changes it gives me errors there cuase it comes null/undefined.

Comment: Can you print screen after changes your network?

Comment: Post updated with the changes results

Comment: I write you demo because its dificult understand

Comment: okay instead of my axios.post/get i changed it to instance and it worked! Thnak you so much for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're using this code in a React component
preferably you have to place this code outside any React lifecycle.

Comment: I'm using it in my App.jsx my parent component of all components

Comment: Yeah this approach works